# Программирование действия в консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

Привет всем!

Возник вопрос, как сделать, чтобы при написании `!clear` в консоль было любое действие. Например: ввел в консоль любой текст и написал !clear и консоль очистилась.

Comment: перехватывать нажатие клавиш и анализировать введенный текст. в случае если найдена команда - выполнять операцию в соответствии с логикой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уже, ребята, отказываетесь от элементарных раздумий! Надо же своим мозгом хоть изредка думать...

```
string read_buffer = Console.ReadLine();
if(read_buffer=="!console")
{
  Console.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Правильно еще будет захэндлить `IOException:`

> Attempting to call the `Clear` method when a console application's output is redirected to a file throws a `IOException`. To prevent this, always wrap a call to the `Clear` method in a `try…catch` block.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, ну, думаю, если начать прикручивать тут всякие фичи, то получится целая микросистема =)